# Optional command line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

My program receives three arguments:

```
int bufferSize
int priority
int milliTimeOut
```

Is there a way to make some of these params optional (and to set these params value as default values)?

For example, if the user want to leave `priority` to be the default priority, but to insert `bufferSize` and `milliTimeOut`, what does he type when he runs my program, and how do I check it in my program?

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on how you parse command line parameters. If you use [Boost program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html) module you can do this way:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int bufferSize;
    int priority;
    int milliTimeOut;

    po::options_description desc("Options for my program");
    desc.add_options()
        // Option 'buffer-size' and 'b' are equivalent.
        ("buffer-size,b", po::value<int>(& bufferSize)->default_value(8192),
            "The buffer's size")
        // Option 'priority' and 'p' are equivalent.
        ("priority,p", po::value<int>(& priority)->default_value(4),
            "The priority")
        // Option 'timeout' and 't' are equivalent.
        ("timeout,t", po::value<int>(& milliTimeOut)->default_value(30000),
            "Time out in ms")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    // Here your variables have the values specified by the user,
    // or the default one.
}
```

Then you call your program like:

```
program --buffer-size=100000 -t 600000
program -b 100000 --priority=10
program -b 5000 -t 50000 -p 15
program
```

The parameters you do not specify get their default value.

You should read the [package documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html), it is quite complete and flexible (e.g. you can have default value only for some parameters).

Answer (score 3):

You can implement *options*, as you often see on Linux.

```
$ program.exe -b 100 -p 1 -m 100
```

where `-b` stands for *bufferSize* followed by a value for it. Similarly, `-p` and `-m` stand for *priority* and *milliTimeOut*, respectively, followed by a value for them.

You write your program to handle this, that is, first parse the *option*, then its value. Then you can know which options are *missing* on the command line. Once you know the *missing* option(s), you can take the default value(s) for it (them).

For example,

```
$ program.exe -b 100 -m 100
```

where `-p` is missing, which means, *priority*  needs to have its default value, decided by your program.

Similarly,

```
$ program.exe -b 100
```

where *priority* and *milliTimeOut* are defaulted.

Comment: you are faster than me, my friend! So let me do a little addition. In windows you use : `program.exe /b 100 /p 1 /m 100 ` by os convention.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: Any convention can be followed. They just need to be documented well. On Windows, you can use `-b` and `/b` both. So you can write your program to handle both of these.

Comment: I know you can use both (There is no one restricting you). I just wanted to say that one can see `/b` like argument passing, and there's no need to panic about it.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı It's not that clear to me what the Windows convention is.  Some Microsoft programs, like the VS compiler (`cl`) accept both `-` and `/` indifferently, which is the convention I'd tend to follow.  (On the other hand, the system accepts both `\` and `/` as file separators, so `/abc` is ambiguous.  Except that as an absolute filename, one expects `c:\abc`.)

Comment: I don't get it why it is ambiguous, `/abc` doesn't indicate a path since windows doesn't have a root concept like UNIX systems. (Maybe you are referring  `./abc` and `.\abc`, and they are completely same as you've already said)

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı On Windows `/` should refer to the current drive's root. If current directory is `C:\some\where` then `/` is the same as `C:\ `, if current directory is `D:\some\where` then `/` is the same as `D:\ `, and so on, so `/abc` is a valid path.

Comment: @Claudio thank you very much for teaching me this, I've known it false. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make arguments optional, and supply default values if none is entered on the command line. Just for example, you could use `-b` to specify a buffer size, and assume 64K if none is entered:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    int bufferSize = 65536;
```

Then comes the tedious code to check whether a command line argument starts with `-b`, and if so, read the desired buffer size from the rest of that argument.

You might want to use Boost [program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html) to ease that somewhat.

Comment: Boost `program_options` is one of the poorer designed boost libraries; it tries to do far too much.  There are widespread simpler solutions, like `getargs`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Why do you think it is *poorer designed*? I would like to know about its poorer side.

Comment: @Nawaz It tries to do to much in a single entity.